# A source generator connected to a receiver with a lossy transmission line

Tags: emc, transmission-line, source

Consider that we have a 50-ohm source generator that is connected to a 300 ohm transmission line. This line has a loss of 10 dB for every 100 ft and is connected to a 50 ohm receiver.

The source indicates an output of -30 dBm and we need to find the input voltage to the receiver in dB(uV).

My steps are as follows :

- First I have converted the source output power (-30 dBm) to the corresponding voltage in absolute value to be equal to 7.07 mV.
- Then I have converted this value to dB (uv) to be equal to 77 dB(uV).
- Finally I have calculated the input voltage to the receiver as V = V
  source (dB (uv))  - loss (dB) = 77 -10 =67 dB (uV) .

However, the answer is 71.7 dB(uV). So what is wrong with my steps?

Edit : This problem is taken from Introduction to electromagnetic compatibility by C.paul.

Comment: You're omitting what you did to come up with your loss number.

Comment: It looks like you aren't accounting for mismatch between the transmission line and the source and load.